# Expensiveness of inheritance and nesting within protobuf-net serialization

Tags: performance, wcf, serialization, protobuf-net

I am using protobuf-net within high-performance wcf services. The serialized objects do have:

- An inheritance depth of 3-4 levels (child class to root class -> could be flattened as well)
- A nesting of objects of 3-4 levels (objects containing objects -> could be flattened as well)

Is there a considerable overhead in dealing with the inheritance and nesting that would give reason to flatten everything to the max?

Thank you for your insights.

Comment: IS this hypothetical, or are you seeing an issue?

Comment: My issue is, that serialization consumes > ~10% of cpu time of the serverside service call processing, so I look for ways to optimize it. See callstack @ http://i.imgur.com/M48d6n8.png